# how to use response data as options for useInfiniteQuery

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-query

In the page where i wanna use useInfiniteQuery

```js
 const { data, error, fetchNextPage, hasNextPage, isFetching, isFetchingNextPage, status } = useInfiniteQuery(
    ['posts', searchState],
    ({ pageParam = 1 }) => post.search({ ...searchState, pageParam }),
    {
      getNextPageParam: (lastPage, pages) => {
        if (pages.length < 2) return pages.length + 1;
        else return undefined;
      },
    },
  );
```

This is my custom axios func:

```js
export const post = {
 search: async (params: { keyword: string; sort: string; region: string; pageParam: number }) => {
    const { keyword, sort, region, pageParam } = params;
    const sortValue = SortType[sort as keyof typeof SortType];
    const url = `/post/search?keyword=${keyword}&page=${pageParam}&filter=${sortValue}&region=${region}`;
    console.log(url);
    const res = await client.get(url);
    return res;
  },
}
```

res in post.search function returns:

```
{"status":200,"message":"search success","data":{"posts":[],"pageCount":0}}
```

And I'd like to use pageCount as a condition for the getNextPageParam func, hasNextPage value.

What i really want to ask is, how can i use pageCount value in the following code:

```js
getNextPageParam: (lastPage, pages) => {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who is not used to using react-query.
You can just simply look up the res.data using lastPage

```
  const { data, error, fetchNextPage, hasNextPage, isFetching, isFetchingNextPage, status } = useInfiniteQuery(
    ['posts', searchState],
    async ({ pageParam = 1 }) => (await post.search({ searchState, pageParam })).data,
    {
      getNextPageParam: (lastPage, allPages) => {
        if (lastPage === undefined) return undefined;
        else return allPages.length < lastPage.pageCount && allPages.length + 1;
      },
    },
  );
```